# Search result URL as permanent link

Tags: seo, links, dynamic

Is it OK to have a dynamically generated result page, like Google Search result page for a specific query, put in your own website as a permanent link. For example: I search for "IT Ebooks" and copy the result page-URL like

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=IT+ebooks&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8
```

and have it as a link in my own web site under Ebooks->IT Ebooks (Only an example to explain my situation). How would it affect my site's SEO?

Comment: Are you referring to a search result page for your own website (as the current answer assumes) or an external website (eg. google.com) as your example suggests?

Answer (score 2):

Google's quality guidelines say that they don't want search results inside of your website indexed, as they don't want users from Google search results to come to your search results (search in search).

So, it is OK for you to put a link to your search results page on your site, but you're recommended to don't allow to index your search results pages. For this, you'd better block their crawling in robots.txt and put noindex meta tag on the code of your search results pages.

Comment: A `rel="nofollow"` on that link would probably be sensible too.

Comment: Thanx... for the answer... but in my situation it is not google search result but a journal search result. Then it is ok I guess.

Comment: As I said, it's OK for you to have a link to it, but it's not OK to allow Google to index your search result pages. That's why you need to block the indexing.

Comment: Regarding the rel="nofollow" attribute on the link - no, you don't need to add it, nofollow means that you do not trust the contents on that page or that page itself. Usually, you want Search Engines to follow your links so they can find, crawl and index other pages that are found on there.